# Processing sketch glitchs when using values depending upon values of x

Tags: java, graphics, processing

My program contains main shapes i.e square, rect, circle they work good ( for x2,y2 in those shapes I used absolute values e.g square( x, y, 5, 5) ), but when working with triangle shape,
 *Triangles in my program glitches*.

below is the code of my program modules,

```
if (vehicleStyle.getVehicleShape().equals(VehicleShape.TRIANGLE)) {
        processingVisualizer
                .fill(vehicleStyle.getColor().red,
                        vehicleStyle.getColor().green,
                        vehicleStyle.getColor().blue);
        processingVisualizer.strokeWeight(1 * vehicleSize);
        //System.out.println(x + "-" + y);

        //## to place face toward movement direction
        /*
         *          -----<|----
         *          |         |
         *         \/         /\
         *          |         |
         *          -----|>----
         */
        float x2, y2, x3, y3;
        if (x == 100) {
            System.out.println( "x==100");
            x2 = x - 5;
            y2 = y + 5;
            x3 = x + 5;
            y3 = y + 5;
            processingVisualizer.triangle(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3);

        } else if (x == 20) {
            System.out.println( "x==20");
            x2 = x - 2;
            y2 = y - 2;
            x3 = x + 2;
            y3 = y - 2;
            processingVisualizer.triangle(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3);
        } else if (y == 100) {
            System.out.println( "y ==100");
            x2 = x - 2;
            y2 = y - 2;
            x3 = x - 2;
            y3 = y + 2;
            processingVisualizer.triangle(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3);
        } else if (y == 20) {
            System.out.println( "y ==20");
            x2 = x+5;//x - 2;
            y2 = y-5;
            x3 = x+5 ;//- 2;
            y3 = y+5;
            processingVisualizer.triangle(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3);
        }
    }
    processingVisualizer.strokeWeight(1);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *glitching*: Is the triangle not drawn or drawn incorrectly? (in the latter, describe what do you see and what did you expect to see) Also, are the `System.out.println()` debug command called as expected?

Comment: @MrGreen_pk did my solution work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't test your code, but my assumption is the "glitch" happens because you are rendering a triangle **only** when your 4 conditions are met. You should update the triangle's corner positions based on your conditions if you like, but render the triangle all time, even when the positions are out of date:

```
if (vehicleStyle.getVehicleShape().equals(VehicleShape.TRIANGLE)) {
        processingVisualizer
                .fill(vehicleStyle.getColor().red,
                        vehicleStyle.getColor().green,
                        vehicleStyle.getColor().blue);
        processingVisualizer.strokeWeight(1 * vehicleSize);
        //System.out.println(x + "-" + y);

        //## to place face toward movement direction
        /*
         *          -----<|----
         *          |         |
         *         \/         /\
         *          |         |
         *          -----|>----
         */


float x2, y2, x3, y3;
    if (x == 100) {
        System.out.println( "x==100");
        x2 = x - 5;
        y2 = y + 5;
        x3 = x + 5;
        y3 = y + 5;

    } else if (x == 20) {
        System.out.println( "x==20");
        x2 = x - 2;
        y2 = y - 2;
        x3 = x + 2;
        y3 = y - 2;
    } else if (y == 100) {
        System.out.println( "y ==100");
        x2 = x - 2;
        y2 = y - 2;
        x3 = x - 2;
        y3 = y + 2;
    } else if (y == 20) {
        System.out.println( "y ==20");
        x2 = x+5;//x - 2;
        y2 = y-5;
        x3 = x+5 ;//- 2;
        y3 = y+5;
    }
    processingVisualizer.triangle(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3);
}
processingVisualizer.strokeWeight(1);
```

}

Also, you can easily compute the direction of motion, if you store the previous position, using the arc tangent function ([atan2()](http://processing.org/reference/atan2_.html)):

```
float angle = atan2(currentY-previousY,currentX-previousX);
```

Here's a quick example:

```
float cx,cy,px,py;//current x,y, previous x,y
float len = 15;

void setup(){
  size(200,200);
  background(255);
}
void draw(){
  //update position - chase mouse with a bit of easing
  cx -= (cx - mouseX) * .035;
  cy -= (cy - mouseY) * .035;
  //find direction of movement based on the current position
  float angle = atan2(cy-py,cx-px);
  //store previous position
  px = cx;
  py = cy;
  //render
  fill(255,10);noStroke();
  rect(0,0,width,height);
  fill(127,32);stroke(0);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(cx,cy);
    pushMatrix();
    rotate(angle);
    triangle(len,0,-len,-len,-len,len);
    line(0,0,len,0);
    popMatrix();
  popMatrix();
}
```

[image: arrow - direction of motion]